# Why Ionic app does not work well on physical device with Android 7 (Samsung galaxy note 5)?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor

I created an application with ionic vue js 3 and i tested it and it ran perfectly on Android 13 (Samsung galaxy note 20 Ultra) but on Android 7 (Samsung Galaxy not 5) it showed such a bad design and not working at all.
`My ionic Info: Ionic Framework : @ionic/vue 7.0.1 @capacitor/android : 4.7.0 @capacitor/core    : 4.7.0 @capacitor/ios     : 4.7.0`

android 13
[image]

android 7
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have  updated Chrome from google play  and it worked fine  Android Webview's device  depends on google chrome installed from the google play store